# Example creating a VSTS build extension using c#

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'd like to put together some VSTS build / release management extensions in C#, although I can find some generic examples using PowerShell it would be handy to have some examples in C#.

Could anyone point me at a C# VSTS extension example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding build task extension, you can specify the C# application, such as console application:

```
"execution": {
    //"PowerShell3": {
    //  "target": "Hello.ps1",
    //  "argumentFormat": ""
    //}
    "Process": {
      "target": "..\\ConsoleApplication1.exe",
      "argumentFormat": "$(ConnectedServiceName) $(currentDirectory) $(ApiPortalName)"
    }
  }
```

However the [Task SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib) are Typescript and PowerShell, so you can’t use the SDK in your application directly, also the newest schema has removed the extra schema info (check [remove extra schema info #308](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/pull/308/commits/5afafff7ea1af91cae83d269a01713c8895becf7)), so NodeJS and PowerShell are the recommended way.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the source of GitVersion.  The authors have wrote a TFS/VSTS task associated with it.  The core of the tool is pure C#.

Here's the code of their TFS Task
https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/tree/master/src/GitVersionTfsTask

Here is the task you'd use inside your builds
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion#overview

Comment: It looked to me like it was TypeScript at the core of that tool. Can you point me towards the C# part? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It looks like they use the .ts file as a runner to then launch the .net core application.